# How do I get ALT-ENTER wordwrap to auto-fit the height the cell EXCEL?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I am using ALT-ENTER for hard word wrapping in a cell.

However, when I use it, the autofit height doesn't work properly. It fits the height of the cell to the first line.

Is there any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a fix for this in one go however did come up with something that worked well enough. It's a bodge for sure.

First count the number of lines in the cell you are looking at by using the following statement.

=LEN(B5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B5,CHAR(10),""))+1

Then use a massive if statement =IF(B82="","",IF(B82=1,"1",IF(B82=2,"1 1",IF(B82=3,"1 1 1",IF(B82=4,"1 1 1 1",IF(B82=5,"1 1 1 1 1",IF(B82=6,"1 1 1 1 1 1",IF(B82=7,"1 1 1 1 1 1 1" and so on

That cell needs to be the width of the "1" and it will then wrap to the height of the other cell. It's not pretty but it worked for me.

Comment: Interesting approach. Instead of the "massive if", why not do `=REPT("1 ", B82)`?

Comment: That's brilliant Scott! Cheers. Had I known this yesterday it would have saved me writing the if statement up 23 times as that was the most the s/s had in the column. Your way means the formula is effectively future proofed no matter the num ber of lines.

Comment: Additionally - you could change the 1 to another word that's more appropriate in width using the =REPT( . 1 was simply for ease of not writing out a longer word repeatedly. Format to white and then no one will know it's there.

Answer (score 0):

All right, so there are a few ways about this -

1. You can double click in between the row labels and it will adjust the row to auto-fit the contents of the largest cells
2. You can do it the old fashioned way and go to *Home → Cells → Format → Autofit Row Height*
3. You can use a keyboard shortcut for #2 - hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> and press <kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>

Unfortunately, you'll need to do this manually because excel doesn't consider a "line break" when autofitting the row height.

Comment: I have tried all of them again and again. However, it didn't work. Can you make a video to show or can you show with screenshots?

Comment: Do you have any merged cells? autofit won't work when there are merged cells.

Comment: No there are no merged cells. The only thing that I do thing I type a word and press alt enter, type again press alt center. Afterwards, I click auto-fit and it only fits till the first line. Not others.

Comment: Try to autofit columns first, then rows. If not, try to adjust the zoom on the spreadsheet to something else and then back.

Comment: I just found that this is happening one and only if I merge a cell. Otherwise it works. I need to find a solution for merged cell.

Comment: Check [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/merged-cells-row-height/c6ce62af-86ac-4b03-a644-92a0ab744f96) out. It's not a simple solution, but it's documented. This is a known limitation of excel.

Comment: You just said you have no merged cells. Then you say it only happens for merged cells. You need to make up your mind.

Answer (score 0):

Often ALT+HOA does not work immediately, or only for some rows in a column.
Often this sequence works:

1. Alt+HOA
2. click in the cell of which the row height should reckon with    Alt+Enter
3. Click in its edit field on top of the Excel-screen
4. Click on another cell in the row with the cell of which the row   height should reckon with Alt+Enter, and Voila (hopefully)

Admittedly, this is a stupid and time-consuming procedure, but gazing at cells in an excel sheet with largely invisible texts may cost even more time.